# How do I convert datestrings with '-' in it to integers when there are also years before 0

Tags: python, string, date, integer

I have a dataframe in Python with one column that depicts different formats of time.

The different formats are

- NaN
- only the Year
- the year, the month
- the year, the month and the date

I cannot convert it to datetime because it has dates before 0. It's about museum objects so some pieces are from -800.

But the strings also sometime show the year, month and day separated by a '-', (for example '1880-04-23'). I can not just convert the '-' to empty strings because then the years before 0 also will be wrong.

Can somebody please help me with this. There are too many different forms to just pick one and delete all the other rows, that would mean the dataset will be very empty in the end.

If only the year is available in the end that would perfect as well, i just want to be able to work with it in integers.

What I tried to do now is iterating over every row in the column and then iterating over the elements of the string within that row starting from the second element, searching for a '-'. This way I can do something like delete everything after the first occurrence of the '-' (and because i start at the second element, if the year is before 0 that '-' will not be seen) or replace those with a '#' so I can split it afterwards.

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    for element in df.loc[i,'columnname_with_dates_as_strings'][1:]:
        element.replace('-','#')
```

But this doesn't work because I get the keyerror: 0
I think my second line is faulty but I don't know why

Comment: What are you using to do that? What language?

Comment: I'm so sorry, in Python

Comment: Maybe change first character '-' to whatever, '#' for example, then split, then change it back. That's more "regex" lazy way but works.
Or just test it first, set a sign "flag" (a variable) if exists, remove, then split, then add it back (if flag was set).

Comment: Not sure how much functionality you need, if not much then maybe you could roll your own class that converted between year/month/day to integer and back to canonical strings using bitmasking or the like.

Comment: Since you have dates well before the epoch of datetime, you may want to look at astronomical date packages in Python. There are many of these.

Comment: It would be easier to do this as pre-processing BEFORE you enter this into `pandas`.  I see too many people trying to battle `pandas` to do processing that is easy to do with Python strings.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def split_date(date_str):
    if date_str[0] == '-':
        sign = 1
    else:
        sign = 0
    date_array = date_str[sign:].split('-')
    return (sign, date_array)

>>>
>>> split_date("1880-04-23")
(0, ['1880', '04', '23'])
>>> split_date("-800")
(1, ['800'])
>>> split_date("-123-5-6")
(1, ['123', '5', '6'])
```